# awk sustituir valor de una columna y cambiar el valor de la otra

Tags: awk

Quiero modificar una línea con una sola columna, me gustaría dividir esta línea en dos columnas, donde el primer valor sea '1', mientras que el nuevo valor de la segunda columna sea el valor de la línea inicial-1.

El código que tengo escrito es el siguiente:

```
awk 'NR==6{$0="H W"}NR==7{$2=$1-1; $1="1 "}{print}' > sc_${i}/POSCAR
```

Sin embargo no me funciona. ¿Alguien sabe como solucionarlo o cual es el problema?

Comment: NR corresponde a la línea, por defecto. Es decir, estás cambiando cosas en la línea 6 y en la línea 7. ¿Realmente es lo que quieres? Por otra parte, añade un [mcve] con ejemplo de entrada, de salida actual y de cómo querrías que fuera.

Comment: Dicho lo cual, a mí `awk '{$2=$1-1; $1="1 "} {print}'` me funciona perfectamente, modificando la 1.ª columna por "1 " y la 2.ª por el valor de la 1.ª menos 1.

Comment: muchas gracias @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' por la ayuda y las correcciones. Exacto, en la línea 6 estoy cambiando cosas también, aunque mi duda no era ahí. Ya logré solucionar el problema, me faltaba un 'sc.POSCAR' antes del signo >, disculpa las molestias!

Comment: ah, claro, no ponías ningún fichero de entrada